# Star Rating with SVG catering for decimal point rating

Tags: angularjs, html, css, svg

I have some code to create a star rating. I have not used SVG before and I can't figure out how to get it to do the following:

- Rating is out of 5
- Display ratings with decimal place ie: 4.5, 3.2, 1.1 as well as whole stars
- Rated stars need to be yellow, stars remaining need to be grey

How and what do I change on the example to move the star rating left and right to get it do display the stars catering for decimals?

Fiddle example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/apbuc773/10/

Code:

```
<svg height="210" width="500" fill="url(#g)">
      <polygon points="165.000, 185.000, 188.511, 197.361, 184.021, 171.180,
 203.042, 152.639,
 176.756, 148.820,
 165.000, 125.000,
 153.244, 148.820,
 126.958, 152.639,
 145.979, 171.180,
 141.489, 197.361,
 165.000, 185.000" style="stroke: red;"/>
    <linearGradient y2="0.9733" x2="1" id="g" x1="0.0167" y1="0.9833">
<stop stop-color="#F00" offset="0.4733"/>
<stop stop-color="rgb(255, 255, 255)" offset="0.5033"/>
</linearGradient>
    </svg>
```

The code attached - is all this needed? As there will be 5 stars in total, can it be simplified.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the `<linearGradient>` with some simple JS. Example below.

```js
function setFraction(fraction)
{
    document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", fraction);
    document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", fraction);
}


setFraction(0.4);
```

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="165.000, 185.000, 188.511, 197.361, 184.021, 171.180,
 203.042, 152.639,
 176.756, 148.820,
 165.000, 125.000,
 153.244, 148.820,
 126.958, 152.639,
 145.979, 171.180,
 141.489, 197.361,
 165.000, 185.000" style="stroke:red; fill:url(#g)"/>
  <linearGradient id="g" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">
    <stop id="stop1" stop-color="#F00" offset="0.5"/>
    <stop id="stop2" stop-color="#fff" offset="0.5"/>
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

If you wanted to avoid JS, then you could create 11 different versions of the star (unfilled, 0.1, 0.2 ... 0.9, filled) and just include the correct one.

Comment: So does the setFraction(value) replace whats in the svg offset? - so this will be the rating? Not sure what you mean or how to do the defining 9 different gradients 0.1 > 0.9? thanks

Comment: setFraction() sets the fraction for one star.  If you wanted to do something like 4.9, then you would need five stars and do a setFraction(0.9) on the last one.

Comment: For the 0.1->0.9 thing I meant that if you didn't want to use JS, you could create nine versions of the star, each showing a different fraction from 0.1 to 0.9. You would then just include the correct one for your rating.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Fiddle with dots:
http://jsfiddle.net/cnLHE/296/

You can place a rectangle underneath masked elements.  In this Fiddle, the rectangle is width=90, which is 90% (at very bottom).

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" style="fill:#2498c7; mask: url(#mask5)"/>
```

Change the 90 to 55, for example, and the underlying fill will shrink width.

Warning: I scrapped this method, because it did not work well with 20+ instances in page.  For example, when loading a grid of rated products, the ratings graphic would sometimes disappear in Chrome.  JS methods were more reliable.

Comment: thanks for the reply - how would this work with the js method?

Comment: Essentially the same thing - create a bar that on click creates a percentage value (which you can store in an invisible text input), and also fills up its color horizontally.  Then place an image overlay above it.

Comment: the star rating is read only as they are pre set - coming from the database. So it is just displaying the actual rating on page

Comment: What does all the svg code mean? such as: userSpaceOnUse, fill white / black and why does each circle different have different code and values?

Comment: Here's a link for them:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute
I think userSpaceOnUse was just to establish the pattern units, so it knows which coordinates to use when beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Change the offset fields from 0 (unfilled) to 1 (filled) to move the rating.

Not sure why you're specifying red in two different ways or why you've slightly different offset values.

Comment: to be honest, im not even sure what its doing myself as ive not done anything with svg before. How would i specify or what value do i need to move in order to change the ratings to something like 4.3, 4.8 etc.

Comment: Draw more stars and make some of them completely red, you only need a gradient for the final star.