# How do I use SVG to fill a vector graph like this?

Tags: animation, svg

How do I fill a svg (with any shape) like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/6dou42qz/

What I expect:

1. Given any number, like 50% or 70%
2. Fill the shape with two colors, split at the given rate. (From left to right)
3. Can dynamic change the fill-rate (better with animation).

Desired code:

```
var $svg = $('#svg_id');
splitFill($svg, 0.5);
splitFill($svg. 0.7); // Animate from 50% to 70%
```

[image]

Comment: Create a linearGradient with stops red, 0% red x% yellow x% yellow 100%.

Comment: @RobertLongson tried to search for some information but many posts are recommending working with a plugin or library. Is there any native way to code? Thanks

Comment: Sure, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks, I have added a jsfiddle link. I can change the color but I don't know how to add gradient fill and make it animated.

Comment: Perhaps my answer to another person's similar question would be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921110/star-rating-with-svg-catering-for-decimal-point-rating/29921496#29921496

Comment: Actually here is another answer. WIth animation this time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276897/jquery-svg-shift-color-animation/34284185#34284185